# Cakephp Authentication not working in Internet Explorer 8 and Chrome

Tags: php, internet-explorer, cakephp, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I followed the tutorial for setting up simple authentication (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) and I am having issues with Internet Explorer 8 and Chrome. Whenever I try to login, it just keeps redirecting me to the login page. This only works in Firefox. Could this be a cookies issue? I am not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Edit: 
I realized this only works in Firefox. I have added a line in the core.php file under the Config folder to disable the checkAgent and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, it was an environmental issue. I was running my webserver/mysql database in an Ubuntu 11.04 virtual machine. I noticed very odd issues occurring. When I created a new virtual machine and loaded my project files, everything was functioning correctly. That was very bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

I can't be sure that this is the same problem, but it may be useful in the future...  have you checked the date on your host machine?

When a cookie has a bad date from an de-synchronized host machine (which happens frequently in my virtual machine environment), Chrome correctly rejects it, which causes the PHP session variables to be lost.  Firefox is more lenient.

It's a simple fix, and it's caught me out more than once in the past!

Answer (score 0):

App Controller sample:
https://github.com/hugodias/cakeStrap/blob/master/app/Controller/AppController.php

Users controller sample:
https://github.com/hugodias/cakeStrap/blob/master/app/Controller/UsersController.php

Users model sample:
https://github.com/hugodias/cakeStrap/blob/master/app/Model/User.php

Login form sample:
https://github.com/hugodias/cakeStrap/blob/master/app/View/Elements/form_login.ctp

Working in all browsers